# Who made this Ant-Man promotional material?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, marketing

I recently found [this promotional video for *Ant-Man*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IRPZ7rf_vk), posted by what I believe to be the offical YouTube channel for Disney Japan, a hilarious but very odd song and dance. Being as it is Japanese, I initially passed it off as "just one of those Japanese things" and let it be.

However, since then I have found other videos with these same two people, dancing to the same song with different lyrics. For one example, please see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSihMD8caS0), or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32XvbVhpWGM) where you can see a talk show of some kind talking about them.

Unfortunately, I have no idea who these people are, and being unable to speak Japansese I am completely incapable of doing any research into it.

**Who are these two people, how is this promotional material for *Ant-Man*, and what on Earth is going on?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The group is "Harsh scan explosion (EGU-SPLOSION)", a Japanese dance troupe/group. Not normally a comedy group. The song/video/meme of Honnoji Incident (probably badly machine translation of 本能寺の変) was first posted in 2015. Like any other funny video, it's been meme'd to death, as seen in [this Vine tag search.](https://vine.co/tags/%E6%9C%AC%E8%83%BD%E5%AF%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%89)

The specific linked video was indeed posted by the official Walt Disney Studios of Japan youtube account ([WaltDisneyStudiosJP](https://www.youtube.com/user/WaltDisneyStudiosJP)), and featured on [the official Disney/Marvel of Japan website.](http://marvel.disney.co.jp/movie/antman/news/201500910_02.html)

[image]

> This time, to give the overwhelming support from dancers such as 20's "Honnoji Incident", dance unit that has been revered as "God", *Egu-Splosion* is, was appointed to the strongest cheer dancer of the movie "Antoman" , it was held an event to show off the cheer song.
>
> Harsh scan explosion that tag with Aikawa Nanase such famous artists and popular comedian is a topic every time.
> Tag of the first time and made the movie this time to realize! It's named after the new hero "Antoman" of the Marvel movie "Honnoji Incident / Antoman version" was showcased in the dance of Kirekire. (Google Translate)

Like a celebrity sponsor for the movie, Disney/Marvel of Japan has simply latched onto a popular meme to promote the Antman movie. Very Genre-Savy of them.

Comment: It's basically the Macarena or the Dougie.

Comment: Your translation to Honnoji Incident seems correct. You work fast, by the way.

Comment: Google Translate. Considering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honnō-ji_incident I don't get the humor behind the song. Also considering I don't understand Japanese.